# javascript incrementally changing opacity and small slider function

Tags: javascript, slider

I can't find the appropriate value in my slider, can you help me, I tried a lot, but I couldn't succeed.

[my demo codepen](https://codepen.io/hankiao/pen/mdzePEr)

[mobile version on the site I want to achieve](https://robin-noguier.com/)

```
    objs.forEach((o,i)=>{

       const getlive = i*0 - this.lastX*livewidth;

        o.dist = Math.min(Math.abs(this.lastX - i),1)
        o.dist = 1 - o.dist**0.8;

        titlew[i].style.opacity = 0 + 1*o.dist;
        elemdots[i].style.opacity = 0.3 + 1*o.dist;
        
        livewrap.style.transform = `translate3d(${getlive}px, 0, 0)`


     
    })
```

```
The name and description are responsive and the value decreases to 0 according to the previous and next slides.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I highly recommend checking out [mcve]. Also be clearer on what it is that you are trying to accomplish and the problem that you are having.